# Как объяснить постановку запятых в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Мне и на этот раз не удалось уйти из леса засветло: лес издавна очаровал меня , всегда удерживал дотемна, и я никогда не мог насладиться досыта его таинственной прелестью.

Answer (score 2):

1. *Лес **очаровал, удерживал*** — первая запятая стоит между однородными сказуемыми.
2. *Лес очаровал, удерживал*, **и** *я не мог насладиться* — вторая запятая стоит перед сочинительным союзом **и**, который связывает две грамматические основы.
3. На месте двоеточия я бы поставила тире — в предложениях с причинно-следственными отношениями двоеточие и тире вариативны.

[**Запятая перед союзом И**](http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/315-zapyatayaperedsyuzomi.html)
[**Вариативные знаки препинания. Двоеточие — тире (п. 4)**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189)

Answer (score 0):

**Вот задание.** Перепишите, вставляя пропущенные буквы, раскрывая скобки. Расставьте знаки препинания.

(1)Мне и на этот раз (не) удалось уйти из леса засветл…(2) Лес издавн… оч…ровал меня всегда удерживал дотемн… и я никогда (не) мог насл…диться досыт… его таинственной прелестью.

Здесь два предложения, **так зачем его переделывать в одно?**

**При общей бессоюзной связи** запятая перед И по основному правилу не ставится. А так как первое предложение осложненное и  имеет собственные знаки, то решение о постановке или отсутствии запятой становится проблематичным.

Comment: Тут вопрос спорный (какое предложение первично?), потому что есть и такое: _(Расставьте знаки препинания.) Страстный любитель природы я и на этот раз не сумел уйти из леса засветло он издавна очаровал меня всегда удерживал дотемна и мне никогда не удавалось насладиться досыта его таинственной прелестью._  https://tooglik.ru/q82433

Comment: Хорошо, тогда здесь  бессоюзная связь как общий элемент, запятая перед союзом И не ставится.